# how to mock $state.params in jasmine unit testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have the following controller EditMeetingCtrl.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('EditMeetingCtrl', EditMeetingCtrl);

    EditMeetingCtrl.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$http', '$translate',
        'meetingService', 'companyService', 'notificationService', 'meeting'];

function EditMeetingCtrl($rootScope, $scope, $state, $http, $translate, meetingService, companyService, notificationService, meeting) {
        $scope.meeting = meeting;

        $scope.companyId = $state.params.companyId;
        $scope.save = save;


        function save() {
            $scope.buttonDisable = true;
            meetingService.saveMeeting($state.params.companyId, $state.params.meetingId, $scope.meeting)
                .success(function(meetingId) {
                   //more code
                });
        }


}
})();
```

EditMeetingCtrlSpec.js test case

```
describe('in EditMeetingCtrl', function () {

    var companyService , meetingService ;

    meetingId = 123321 ;                      
    companyId = 456654 ;
    meetingObj = {} ;

    var fakeHttpPromise = {
                            success: function() {}
                          };

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _companyService_ , _meetingService_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        companyService = _companyService_;
        meetingService = _meetingService_ ;
    }));

    describe('EditMeetingCtrl.save()', function () {
        var $rootScope, scope, $controller , $q  ;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller , _meetingService_ ) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            createController = function() {
                return $controller('EditMeetingCtrl', {
                $scope: scope,
                meeting : {} ,
                meetingService : _meetingService_
                }); 
            };
            var controller = new createController();
        }));

        it("should save the meeting object", function() {
            spyOn(meetingService, 'saveMeeting').and.returnValue(fakeHttpPromise);
            scope.save();
            expect(meetingService.saveMeeting).toHaveBeenCalledWith( meetingId , companyId , meetingObj);
        });

    });

});
```

When try to run the below test casse EditMeetingCtrlSpec.js i got the following test failure

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8) EditMeetingCtrl Spying --> EditMeetingCtrl.save() should save the meeting FAILED
        Expected spy saveMeeting to have been called with [ 123321, 456654, Object({  }) ] but actual calls were [ undef
ined, undefined, Object({  }) ].
```

So the way understand my this problem , the service call for `save()` method contains  `$state.params.companyId, $state.params.meetingId` parameters and it sends an `undefined` values when the service call get invoked . therefore i need to mock the the `$state.params` . Not sure how to do it .can anyone point me in the right direction ?

**EDIT after Michael Radionov Answer**

```
describe('EditMeetingCtrl.save()', function () {
        var $rootScope, scope, $controller , $q  , $state ;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller , $state , _meetingService_ ) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            createController = function() {
                return $controller('EditMeetingCtrl', {
                $scope: scope,
                meeting : {} ,
                meetingService : _meetingService_
                }); 
            };
            var controller = new createController();
        }));

        it("should save the meeting", function() {
            $state.params = { companyId: 123, meetingId: 567 };
            spyOn(meetingService, 'saveMeeting').and.returnValue(fakeHttpPromise);
            scope.save();
            //expect(meetingService.saveMeeting).toHaveBeenCalledWith( meetingId , companyId , meetingObj);
        });

    });
```

I have done the above, but i get the following error saying $state is not defined .

```
Firefox 38.0.0 (Windows 8.1) In EditMeetingCtrl EditMeetingCtrl.save() should save the meeting FAILED
        TypeError: $state is undefined in C:/Users/sal/Documents/myApp/test/meeting/EditMe
etingCtrlSpec.js (line 80)
```

I assumed this happened because i did not do this -> `$state : state` in the inject method, so i tried doing that too but got the same error . what am i missing here  ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can mock the entire `$state` provider and then specify exactly what values do you want to be in the `params` property before calling `save`:

```
describe('in EditMeetingCtrl', function () {

    // ...
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {

        // mock the entire $state provider
        $provide.provider('$state', function () {
            return {
                $get: function () {
                    return {
                        // by default it will be an empty object
                        params: {}
                    };
                }
            };
        });

    }));

    // ....

    describe('EditMeetingCtrl.save()', function () {

        // inject mocked $state - one that you've provided above

        var $rootScope, scope, $controller, $q, state;
        // ---------------------------------------^^^

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $state, _meetingService) {
            // ------------------------------------------------^^^
            state = $state;
        }));

        // ...

        it("should save the meeting object", function() {

            // provide custom params which will be used in a call
            state.params = { companyId: 123, meetingId: 567 };

            spyOn(meetingService, 'saveMeeting').and.returnValue(fakeHttpPromise);
            scope.save();
            expect(meetingService.saveMeeting).toHaveBeenCalledWith( meetingId , companyId , meetingObj);
        });
    });

    // ...

});
```

Comment: thank you for your reply . Please look at the edit i have done in my question . ? what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: I think it is because of wrong variable names. Use `var state;`, then when injecting use `state = $state`, and in the `it` block use `state.params`. I've updated my answer, see the edit link.

Comment: Thank you !! . That worked . and now i know what i was doing wrong .:)